# Replacing with sed expression

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to get a value such as

```
"909,999"
```

With this (the example is replacing it with nothing):

```
sed 's/["][0-9]+[,][0-9]+["]//g'
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is the text that you are feeding into `sed`?  Does it work if you run with `sed -E` (your expression looks like an extended regular expression, unless the pluses are supposed to be literal).  Why do you use `["]` instead of just `"`?  The double quote is not special in a regular expression. Likewise for the comma.  Also, you _are_ replacing the matched thing with _nothing_.

Comment: @Kusalananda -E did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the pattern, you can use `sed -E` or escape the `+` characters as suggested by @Kusalananda:

```
$ printf '"123.456"\n"909,999"\n"100"\n' | sed -E 's/"[0-9]+,[0-9]+"//g'
"123.456"

"100"
```

or

```
$ printf '"123.456"\n"909,999"\n"100"\n' | sed 's/"[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+"//g'
"123.456"

"100"
```

Note that the `g` is not needed in this example as there is only one substitution per line.

If you want to delete the matching line(s), you could use `d` to delete the pattern space:

```
$ printf '"123.456"\n"909,999"\n"100"\n' | sed '/"[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+"/d'
"123.456"
"100"
```

Comment: Thank you Freddy. -E worked.